# JHipster (Spring, Angular), Vagrant - empty replay from server

Tags: angularjs, spring, vagrant, cas, jhipster

I configured [demo-spring-cas-angular](http://github.com/jgribonvald/demo-spring-cas-angular)
to work on port 8081. When I run it on my machine (OSX) it works very well.

I have problem when it is run inside vagrant. Port 8081 is forwarded

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8081, host: 8081
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8761, host: 8761
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 5432
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8443, host: 8443
```

I don't have problems with other ports besides 8081 (I have access to databases, eureka registry, CAS instance).

From OSX:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/index.html#/
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

From vagrant:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/index.html#/
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
...
```

I don't see any exceptions during application boot.

```
Access URLs:
----------------------------------------------------------
    Local:      http://127.0.0.1:8081
    External:   http://127.0.0.1:8081
----------------------------------------------------------
```

It is problem with application or with vagrant? I tried to run another application on 8081 - problem didn't occur.

Comment: just to make sure, you don't have conflict on port 8081 (process running on host) when you boot your VM ?

Comment: 8081 is used by VBoxHeadl. During machine startup forwarding seems ok
`default: 8081 (guest) => 8081 (host) (adapter 1)`

Comment: shutdown the VM and run netstat to make sure 8081 is free - You can also change the port forwarding `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8081, host: 8088` or another free port (check with netstat) and see if it works better

Comment: When vagrant is down 8081 is free, after forwarding 8081 to 8088 I still get empty replay

Comment: can you show your `application-dev.yml` file ?

Comment: Yes, it's [here](http://pastebin.com/rrusULr9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the host info from `application-dev.yml` to be

```
server:
    port: 8081
    address: 0.0.0.0
```

so it will be available outside of the VM

`127.0.0.1` is a [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface) address so if you assign this IP (or localhost) to the config of your server, its not accessible from other network interfaces, so you cannot access it from outside of the VM. If you bind your server to [`0.0.0.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) its available to all interfaces

Comment: Didn't help - [some curl calls](http://pastebin.com/nWSb1ZsN). Port 8081 is forwarded to 8081 of course.

Comment: sorry I had some left over from copy/paste; server address must be 0.0.0.0 not 0.0.0.1

Comment: Now everything is ok. Thank you :) Do you have any idea why I'm not able to forward this port like the other ones?

Comment: its not with the port forwarding, port forwarding is working ok - the issue is the the `127.0.0.1`which is a loopback address within the VM so you cannot access the server from outside of the VM.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you for your help