# How to run angular-cli from Vagrant box?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've installed angular-cli with node v6.5.0 and npm v3.10.3 to my vagrant (Scotch) box. After running 'ng serve --port 4201' I can see that the build was successful and that the app is now serving on http://localhost:4201/

However I can't just use above address because I'm running on VM. I've tried to add '127.0.0.1:4201' to hosts file on host machine, but can't get anything working.

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vagrant (VM) doesn't trigger file change events. This bug is reported to VirtualBox community and is set to **won't fix**. For now it's not possible to work with Angular 2 via Vagrant. See [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bevry/watchr/issues/34#issuecomment-22386666) for relevant discussion on this.

Comment: This isn't the problem the original poster is having. He's trying to reach the Angular server on the VM from the host, and failing. You're talking about problems with automatic recompilation due to lack of file change events in vboxfs. Completely different issues.

Comment: This is useful to know, and can be remedied by using `ng serve --poll=2000`. However this does not answer the question the original poster posed. That can be remedied by using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 38):

Run `ng serve` like this:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

This will make the server in your vagrant machine accessible from outside using its ip (mine is 192.168.10.10 using homestead) and the default `4200` port for `angular serve` (http://192.168.10.10:4200).

Some more info:

- [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39076405/5869296):

> 127.0.0.1 is a loopback address so if you assign this IP (or localhost) to the config of your server, its not accessible from other network interfaces, so you cannot access it from outside of the VM. If you bind your server to 0.0.0.0 its available to all interfaces

- [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-and-serving-an-angular2-project-via-a-development-server)

Comment: There's also the issue of the FS events not propagating to Vagrant (as mentioned in a comment in another answer below) and preventing the recompile. I found that using this plugin was the easiest way to get it working (vagrant-fsnotify below requires commands be run every time, this one does not): https://github.com/mhallin/vagrant-notify-forwarder

Comment: In case of live reload doesn't work in vagrant try `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll=2000`

Comment: Legend! Thank you. Anyone else using Vagrant, remember to forward your port 4200.

Answer (score 7):

You have to add some config to Vagrantfile.

To access site add these lines (it helped me):

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.100"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4200, host: 4200
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 49152, host: 49152
```

You can access site on: http://192.168.100.100:4200/

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, does your nodewatcher works fine on vagrant? My doesn't react to any code changes

Comment: Hey @rvaliev, i didn't see the question. There is a workaround to use this plugin: https://github.com/adrienkohlbecker/vagrant-fsnotify with vagrant, which makes changes also on the guest.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately after an update to the last version of angular-cli (1.0.0-beta.17) and Angular 2.0.0 final, I can't get angular running. It builds successfully, but I can't access the project from host machine via 192.168.100.100:4200. In Chrome I get message like: "192.168.100.100 refused to connect." :(

Comment: You need to serve the site as ng serve --host 192.168.100.100