# How can I set up a dependably clean, fully functional Angular 2 environment?

Tags: node.js, angular, build, development-environment

I'm learning Angular 2, and am making good progress. But, now that I'm starting to try optimized builds with tree shaking, I keep getting explosions of error messages deep in the Angular code. These may be caused by Angular/npm/tsc/uglifyjs bugs, but more likely it's a problem in my build environment, as Angular has been in flux and I've been messing around with node for a while and likely have multiple versions of various tools in various locations.

I'd love to have a clean build environment that I knew was completely working, so that I would only have to struggle with my own bugs, rather than with the vastly more complex bugs that a broken build environment could trigger.

Some possibilities:

- Figure out how to remove all traces of node, angular and related tools from my (OS X 10.10.5) machine, and then reinstall from clean, up-to-date sources. I'd likely need a way to test whether an obscure/unauthorized copy of a tool was being run.
- Use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to set up and run a clean environment. However, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39556295/2190921) states that vagrant won't trigger file change events, which I presume would break automatic recompiles. That wouldn't be great, but also wouldn't be that bad.
- Use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) to set up a full virtual machine, or to run an existing fully-updated appliance. However, that's a lot of overhead for what should be a simple task.

Any suggestions?

Edit: another concern is that I'm not the only developer that will be working on this code. If our build environments differ then we could be driven nuts trying to chase down each other's build problems. This points to a portable system such as Vagrant or VirtualBox.

Comment: I would remove all traces of nodes and others developer toos from your machine and then setup a segregate virtual environment (any you prefer) for development. This will save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the official `angular-cli`? It uses webpack for bundling and treeshaking out of the box.

Comment: My understanding is that the Angular 2 CLI isn't ready for production yet (see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli, which says "This project is very much still a work in progress").

Comment: I've been using it for 6 months now. There was a moment when it was really painfaul to be an early-adopter (migration from SystemJS to Webpack), but right now it's a breeze. I use it for 3 projects, two of which are in production. Your call :)