# Vagrant Puppet, unable to install @angular/cli

Tags: angular, puppet, angular-cli

I have these resources on my `default.pp` file:

```
class { 'nodejs':
  repo_url_suffix => '8.x',
}
-> package {
  'gulp':
    ensure   => 'present',
    provider => 'npm';
  'webpack':
    ensure   => 'present',
    provider => 'npm';
  'pm2':
    ensure   => 'present',
    require  => Class['nodejs'],
    provider => 'npm';
  '@angular/cli':
    ensure   => 'present',
    provider => 'npm';
}
```

and while trying to setup the Vagrant instance, it gets stuck and no more activity on the screen:

```
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs::Install/Package[nodejs]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Package[gulp]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Package[webpack]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Package[pm2]/ensure: created
```

I've tried this too:

```
  'pm2':
    ensure   => 'present',
    require  => Class['nodejs'],
    provider => 'npm';
}
-> exec { 'Install Angular CLI':
  command => '/usr/bin/npm install --global @angular/cli',
  creates => '/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng'
}
```

But the only difference is that this time I get a timeout:

```
==> default: Error: Command exceeded timeout
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[Install Angular CLI]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Command exceeded timeout
```

After this timeout, `vagrant up` finalizes the tasks and I'm able to log in with `vagrant ssh` and check that it installed successfully:

```
which ng: /usr/bin/ng
```

so I'm suspecting the timeout is due to the returned status of `@angular/cli` installation.

Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Maybe check this out. I am not familiar with it but these guys seem to think there is a pending problem to be fixed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400383/how-to-run-angular-cli-from-vagrant-box

Comment: @EyoelD that's an old issue, I think Virtualbox and Vagrant had evolved a ton these 3 years. Perhaps, this issue with the Puppet manifest is kinda weird.

Comment: Switching to an `exec` resource and discovering the timeout actually helps determine the root cause. An `exec` resource times out by default after five minutes, but other resources like `package` will hang as long as possible (I have seen over twenty-four hours). Try spinning up the Vagrant instance without the provisioning and then applying the manifest with `debug` and see what happens.

Comment: what is the guestOS puppet is being run in? what is the version of puppet on the guestOS?

Comment: @andrewleung I have Ubuntu 17.04 zesty, the Vagrant vm.box used is `debian/contrib-jessie64` and installs puppet `4.10.8`

Comment: hmmm... is `sudo` required? also, what is the full path to the npm executable? I know puppet likes to have direct paths to binaries (i.e. having puppet run `echo` requires: `path => '/bin/echo'` instead of just `path => echo`...

Comment: @andrewleung I updated the description of the problem. I already tried `/usr/bin/npm install --global @angular/cli` but didn't work. Added ` || /bin/echo "done"` to avoid the return `0` of the timeout, but no joy either. I'm running out of ideas :(