# Angular CLI: Live reload not working with Vagrant

Tags: angular, vagrant

I'm upgrading from Angular 8 to Angular 9, and now finding that the Live Reload for the CLI is no longer working while using a Vagrant development environment.  The app does not recompile when changes are made to the codebase.

I've tried vagrant-fsnotify and vagrant-notify-forwarder with no luck.  I'd like to avoid using polling since it's already resource intensive running the dev server for other members of my team.

Angular: 9.1.10
Angular CLI: 9.1.7
Host OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4
Guest OS: Debian 10.4
Vagrant: 2.2.9

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400383/how-to-run-angular-cli-from-vagrant-box

Comment: @Harinath Yes I have Vagrant setup with port forwarding and have tried the suggestions in that post with no luck.  Live Reload has worked in our development setup up to Angular 8, so I wasn't really expecting a post from 2016 to provide a solution, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For, me this command works for me

```bash
ng serve --poll=2000
```